IntelliJ Java and Kotlin project - Kotlin: Unresolved reference
I have a Java Maven project where the files in the test project (Selenium and Cucumber) are Kotlin files. This project has been running and working for a long time. After a computer crash, I've been forced to set up my IntelliJ, docker and Maven environment from scratch.
After importing the project and setting it up, I'm encountering the following problem when trying to run Selenium/Cucumber tests:
Kotlin: Unresolved reference

Now, starting at the top of the error list, it's a .kt file which imports another kotlin file:
import e2e.login.LoginSteps

Standing in the editor, there is no red marking or error on the line in question, and I can Ctrl-click the import and open the imported package/file. So, the connections seems to work.
I can also run the test from the command line, with "mvn clean install". The Cucumber and Selenium tests fire up and run normally. But not when I try executing a single test or a feature from inside IntelliJ.
Here's my IntelliJ setup, for troubleshooting:
Settings
 - Build, Execution, Deployment
  - Compiler
   - Java Compiler: Target bytecode version for all modules: 21
   - Kotlin Compiler: Kotlin Compiler version: 1.9.22, Language version: 1.9, API version: Latest stable (2.0), Target JVM version: 21

Project Structure
 - Project Settings
  - Project -> SDK: 21 Eclipse Temurin 21.0.3, Language level: 21
 - Platform Settings
  - SDKs: 21

Some support resources suggest mismatch between the target JVM version from Kotlin, and the JVM version in use. But as far as I can tell, this is correct in the above setup.
Ideas? Other places/things to check?

Delete .idea directory from the project and re-import it from pom.xml. If it doesn't help, contact support with the sample project to reproduce.

"Contact support with sample project" - that's the standard reply. However, do you know many coorporate projects that can be given to IntelliJs support? And since the problem is with this exact project, creating another sample project is naturally not an option. Also - deleting the .idea folder when the project is fresh from the repo is just...doesn't make much sense.

We don't know what's in your repository and the current contents of .idea folder. If you tried it and it doesn't help, there is no good way to get help regarding such problems without a sample project, unfortunately.
